Override rect type in v-network-graph
I'm using v-network-graph in vue project. I'm trying to override node with rect type because I need to put inside the box some information.
I can see in the documentation that you can override this node, like this:
<template #override-node="{ nodeId, scale, config, ...slotProps }">
  <circle :r="config.radius * scale" :fill="config.color" v-bind="slotProps" />
  <!-- Use v-html to interpret escape sequences for icon characters. -->
  <text
    font-family="Material Icons"
    :font-size="22 * scale"
    fill="#ffffff"
    text-anchor="middle"
    dominant-baseline="central"
    style="pointer-events: none"
    v-html="nodes[nodeId].icon"
  />
</template>

Documentation: here
In the documentation I can't find anything about override the square shape. I read the github code and I found this
I have tried to implement it like this:
<template
  #override-node="{
    scale, config,
    slotProps,
  }"
>
  {{ console.log("x", config) }}
  <rect
    class="v-ng-svg-rect"
    :rx="config.borderRadius * scale"
    :ry="config.borderRadius * scale"
    :width="config.width"
    :height="config.height"
    :fill="config.color"
    v-bind="slotProps"
    :stroke="config.strokeColor"
    :stroke-width="config.strokeWidth * scale"
  />
 
</template>

And this is my result:
Overrided nodes
And if I remove the overrided code, I have perfect boxes:
Perfect nodes
But I can't (or maybe I don't know how to do) put any text inside the box.
Any idea?? Thanks :)
